# WooCommerce single-content-products cached?

Tags: php, wordpress, caching, server, woocommerce

I've got an webshop running on WooCommerce & Wordpress, everything works fine but i have to do a little update in the content-single-product.php, in my own theme i've made a WooCommerce folder and put my custom template in there. How ever updates i do there don't show live it basically shows the old template so i think something is caching this specific template, because all other templates i edit work fine and show the latest version.

I've even deleted the content-single-product.php (one in WooCommerce plugin folder & the template in my own theme) from the server, and it still shows the old template. I've disabled my browsers cache (developer tools open), cleared cache manually and don't have any caching plugins.

Note: on localhost updates do show correctly just the server seems to cache the file, anything i could do to solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Where is your site hosted?

Comment: Are you using cloudflare or anything like that? Or is there something your host might be doing to cache? Alternatively maybe try quickly deactivating and deactivating Woocommerce to see if that flushes anything.

Comment: In that case your hosting server is using a cache… You have to ask your hosting provider…

Comment: Ye i contacted them 30 minutes ago seems to be something with the server, tried re-activating WooCommerce and it didn't flush it sad enough, thanks for the suggestion tho!